# Rails 2.2 - rake task loading gems after lib and so losing patches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In my lib folder i have various files which patch various core classes and gems in rails.  When i run rails (unicorn, mongrel, the console), the gems get loaded first and then the patches in lib, so that the lib patches override the gems.

When i run a rake task, however, the lib files are loaded *before* the gems, meaning that the original gem methods override the patches and the patches are effectively ignored.

Does anyone know how i can fix this?  My Rakefile just has this:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'
```

The rake task i'm running is set up like this:

```
desc "blah"
task :convert_worlds, [:new_instrument] => :environment do |t, args|  
  ...
end
```

Grateful for any advice - Max

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ? I have a similar problem

Comment: No, i never did :/  I ended up just working around it which is quite unsatisfactory.